# Self referencing LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following c# code:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var tasks = new[]
        {
            new Task {id = 1, name = "Task 1", dependencyId = 0},
            new Task {id = 2, name = "Task 2", dependencyId = 1},
            new Task {id = 3, name = "Task 3", dependencyId = 2},
            new Task {id = 4, name = "Task 4", dependencyId = 3},
            new Task {id = 5, name = "Task 5", dependencyId = 0},
        };

        var listOfTasks = (from t in tasks
                 join dt in tasks
                     on t.id equals dt.dependencyId into JoinedTasks
                 from jt in JoinedTasks
                 select new TaskWithDependency
                    {
                        Task = jt,
                        DependentTask = t
                    }).ToList();

        foreach (var z in listOfTasks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(z.Task.name + " depends on: " + (z.DependentTask != null ? z.DependentTask.name : ""));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}

public class TaskWithDependency
{
    public Task Task { get; set; }
    public Task DependentTask { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int dependencyId { get; set; }
}
```

How can I use LINQ to project into an `IEnumerable<TaskWithDependency>`.I'm, effectively trying to acheive a self join. The result should be an `IEnumerable<TaskWithDependency>` where in this example only the first `TaskWithDependency` has a dependency.

Comment: _What_ is the desired result? That's not clear at all.

Comment: If the result should be an `IEnumerable<TaskWithDependency>`, you must support looking up a `TaskWithDependency` by its `dependencyId`. Alternatively, returning an `IEnumerable<Task>` from some root is trivial. Which one is it?

Comment: I've editied my original question. The DependentTask in TaskWithDependency class should have been of type Task, not IEnumerable<Task>. I've also added the LINQ expression I've currently got. Its nearly correct, ideally it would return all tasks (left join) regardless if they have a dependent task or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var tasksTransformed = tasks.Select(x => new TaskWithDependency
{
    Task = x,
    DependentTask = tasks.Where(y => y.DependencyId == x.id)
}
```

Comment: You may want to call ToList() in both enumerations as well. Also note that this algorithm is O(n^2), which means that if you have lots of elements, it will be slow. The next level is doing a GroupBy().ToDictionary() and then doing the lookups from that, this way it will be O(n):

Comment: Nearly correct, just needed ```FirstOrDefault``` instead of ```Where``` clausse. ```IEnumerable<TaskWithDependency> listOfTasks = tasks.Select(t => new TaskWithDependency() { Task = t, DependentTask = tasks.FirstOrDefault(dt => dt.dependencyId == t.id) });```

Comment: In my defence, in your original question, dependent tasks was an enumeration :). Be careful with FirstOrDefault(), it doesn't handle the case when there are multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for :

```
IEnumerable<TaskWithDependency> tasksWithDep = tasks.Select(t => new TaskWithDependency() { Task = t, DependentTask = tasks.Where(dt => dt.dependencyId == t.id) });
```